# How do I refer to intelligent life?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do I refer to intelligent life? In English we tend to use *sentient* or *sapient*. (Although, *sentient* is technically incorrect, but it tends to be used more often.)

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer should work: *inteligenta vivo*, referring to living things who are capable of reason, *raciaj estaĵoj*, or *vivuloj kapablaj je rezono*.

In *Monato*, SETI is glossed as *Serĉado de Ekstertera Inteligenteco*.

An intelligent, extraterrestrial being is an *inteligenta, ekstertera vivulo/estaĵo*, or an *eksterterano*.

The English words *sentient* and *sapient* are quite ambiguous. *Sentient* may mean "able to sense" or "able to perceive" (a plant or machine can do the former, but not the latter) while *sapient* may mean "wise", or simply "rational" at the level of *homo sapiens*.

- *Senspova* (or *sensiva*) means "able to sense."
- *Sentpova* (or *sentiva*) means "able to feel."
- *Perceptpova* (or *perceptiva*) means "able to perceive."
- *Saĝa* means "wise", the original meaning of *sapient*.
- *Racia* means "reasonable, rational, having to do with reason."
- *Rezonpova* (or *rezoniva*) means specifically "able to reason."

Note that *-iva* is an unofficial suffix meaning *pova, kapabla*, used to preserve the original forms of certain European words. It is a little problematic and some prefer to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

**If you mean just intelligent life:**

- Intelligent = Inteligenta
- Life (something that is alive) = Vivaĵo
- Do you know that there is intelligent life in the ocean? = Cxu vi scias, ke la inteligenta vivajxo ekzistas en la maro?

**If you mean aliens - From the tekstaro:**

- ...la temoj “Vivo ekster la Tero” kaj “Serĉado de *Ekstertera Inteligenteco*”...
- Kiam li pridiskutas la temon “Komunikado kun *Ekstertera Civilizacio*...”